# Android - AdMob click count

Tags: android, admob

I'm writing free game for Android and im going to use AdMob. I have a question regarding clicking adds. I know I can check when user clicked the add by onClick handler in AdView. Id like to implement a feature to give user some 'special bonuses' for clicking adds. Which method is better for capturing adds clicks, onClick or onDismissScreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think onDismissScreen is a more cleaner way. But be careful , forcing user to click ads may violate Admob TOS.

Comment: It definitely violates the TOS and your account will be closed pretty quickly.